# Swift Generic 2d Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, generics, multidimensional-array

I'm looking to do something relatively simple. I want a 2 dimension array of a generic type.  From what I understand, I should use two sets of square braces surrounding the base type, and I can use the simplified loop expression to init the values. 
I have the below code, but I'm receiving an error, `cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializes`.  Below is the code I'm using. Thank you in advance for any help.

```
array = [[Element]](count: 3, repeatedValue: Element(count: 2, repeatedValue: nil))
```

edit : 
I wanted to provide the full source of the code I'm working with

```
struct Array2D<Element> {
    let columns: Int
    let rows: Int
    private var array: Array<Element?>

    init(columns: Int, rows: Int) {
        self.columns = columns
        self.rows = rows
        array = [[Element]](count: 3, repeatedValue: Element(count: 2, repeatedValue: nil))
    }

    subscript(column: Int, row: Int) -> Element? {
        get {
            return array[row*columns + column]
        }
        set {
            array[row*columns + column] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The

```
private var array: Array<Element?>
```

property in `Array2D` is a normal ("one-dimensional")
array used for the storage of the `rows * columns` elements. It must be initialized with:

```
array = [Element?](count: rows * columns, repeatedValue: nil)
```

or just (because the type is known):

```
array = Array(count: rows * columns, repeatedValue: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift doesn't know `Element` has an intializer for the `Element` type.

Here's how you can do it with a helper class:

```
class TwoDArray<T> {
    static func create(initialValue: T, rows: Int, cols: Int) -> [[T]] {
        let tmp = [T](count: cols, repeatedValue: initialValue)
        return [[T]](count: rows, repeatedValue: tmp)
    }
}

let result = TwoDArray.create(42, rows: 3, cols: 2)
```

If you want to initiate the array with `nil`, you have to supply an optional type:

```
let result = TwoDArray<Int?>.create(nil, rows: 3, cols: 2)
```